# Use the face filters such as "Wolf face" with sceneform without ARcore

Tags: android, sceneform

I tried running a sample app, which keep opening play store for ARcore, with a toast saying `Failed to create ar session`.
I just wanna use face filters.

---

Comment: please share some code to get some help ;)

Comment: Is the device capable of using AR Core, and if so, is it installed? If you don't want to use AR Core, does the manifest declare the app as AR Optional, rather than AR Required?

Comment: No, the device is not AR capable, but that is also my target(most devices), and yes i declared it optional, but upon debugging it still opens up app store for AR core.